# How do I translate some complex routes from  Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on a project where I am upgrading a Rails 2.3 application to Rails 3.1. There is one thing which I am not able to figure out. Below is a route defined in a Rails 2.3 application:

```
map.resources :segments, :collection => { :listen => :get, :comment => :post, :inside => :post, :around => :post , :suggest => :get, :ipeds => :get, :search_ipeds => :get }, :member => { :listen => :get }, :has_many => [ :photos , :school_statistics, :comments, :ad_spots ] do |segments|
    segments.resources :visits , :only => [ :index ], :collection => { :destroy_all => :delete }
  end
```

I am not sure how to write this route using Rails 3.1 to perform the same functionality which this route is performing using Rails 2.3. I   searched online to find some resources which explains this  and also I  read the routes documentation on the Ruby on Rails website but I still can't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

free coding here but I guess this would do it for you

```
resources :segments do
  collection do
    get 'listen' 
    post 'comment'
    post 'inside'
    post 'around'
    get 'suggest'
    get 'ipeds'
    get 'search_ipeds'
  end 
  member do
    get 'listen'
  end
  resources :photos 
  resources :school_statistics
  resources :comments
  resources :ad_spots
  resources :visits , :only => [ :index ] do 
    delete 'destroy_all', :on => :collection
  end
end
```

Comment: @ yper : Thanks for the help. It appears to me you are right.